# 'react/no-unused-state' warning while the state field is used in 'componentDidMount' method

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am using eslint in my project but I get warning 'react/no-unused-state' while the state field is used in 'componentDidMount' method. It is saying 'react/no-unused-state' and i couldn't find the solution. Please help. Thank you.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header/header.component';
import { auth } from './firebase/firebase.utils';
import Homepage from './pages/homepage/homepage.components';
import ShopPage from './pages/shop/shop.component';
import SignInAndSignOut from './pages/sign-in-and-sign-out-page/sign-in-and-sign-out-page.component';

class App extends React.Component {
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null,  // line 16
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: user }); // line 22

      console.log(user);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInAndSignOut} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Error I got**

```
src\App.js
  Line 16:7:   Unused state field: 'currentUser'  react/no-unused-state
  Line 22:23:  Unused state field: 'currentUser'  react/no-unused-state
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: It's just as the error says. You're not accessing the state anywhere. What's the point of setting it if you never use it?

Comment: yes, you are right, I am really surprised that I couldn't see the difference between setState and unused state. This small issue was out of my focus. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting up `state` in the `constructor` here:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        currentUser: null,  // Here you're initialising state.
    };
}
```

And you're updating `state` here:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        this.setState({ currentUser: user }); // Here you're updating state.

        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

But you're actually never using `state`. Without using it, there's actually no need to have it. Though I assume you're planning on using it, and if that's the case, all you need to do is reference the `currentUser` in `state` and it `eslint error` will go away

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped you, could you mark it as accepted?